# geo-autocomplete not work after page refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, asp-classic

I use geo-autocomplete in may asp.net application . My problem is that when first time i write something on my text box where i used geo-autocomplete this display the result. But i have one autopost back textbox event on my page, When they fire the google  geo-autocomplete not working, My html for google-autocomplete is this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.autocomplete_geomod.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/geo_autocomplete.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/jquery.autocomplete.css" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('<%=map_canvas.ClientID %>'), myOptions);

        // use all the autocomplete options as documented at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete
        /* additional geo_autocomplete options:
        mapkey : 'ABQ...' (required for Static Maps thumbnails, obtain a key for your site from http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html)
        mapwidth : 100
        mapheight : 100
        maptype : 'terrain' (see http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#MapTypes)
        mapsensor : true or false
        */
        $('#<%=txtPickupCity.ClientID %>').geo_autocomplete(new google.maps.Geocoder, {
            mapkey: 'ABQIAAAAbnvDoAoYOSW2iqoXiGTpYBTIx7cuHpcaq3fYV4NM0BaZl8OxDxS9pQpgJkMv0RxjVl6cDGhDNERjaQ',
            selectFirst: false,
            minChars: 3,
            cacheLength: 50,
            width: 300,
            scroll: true,
            scrollHeight: 330
        }).result(function(_event, _data) {
            if (_data) map.fitBounds(_data.geometry.viewport);
        });

    });
</script>
<style>
.ac_results li img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Here is my text box on which i am using geo code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPickupCity" runat="server" MaxLength="50" 
                                                            Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all i expend 4 hours on google to find out ansqwer this problem at last this is simple

on your Page_load () you use this code that will help you

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "delCty", "delCity();", true);
```

Here "delCty" is Key "delCity()" is function name . Yes means i give function name of  function

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function delCity() 
{
}
```

Enjoy coding . I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same case as I experienced once, but you can try this:
If Latitude and/or Langitude is not set (that means if it doesn't have any value), my JavaScript simply didn't work. So I added a condition (the code isn't in any particular programming language) and my problem was gone:

```
If Latitude = "" then Latitude = 0
If Langitude = "" then Langitude = 0
```

Comment: Problem because  after post back this problem arise.  Means when my update panel update then this stop to work